# How can I call different behaviors at any time during a dialog?

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I have created different behaviors (mini-games). Pepper should run the different games on command during a dialog. I have already tried to put all mini-games within a behaviors into folders and call them verbally with a choice. But it did not work.

Does anyone have another suggestion for calling behaviors or a solution for the choice concept? 
Thank you for any help!

[Screenshot Choregraphe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzj8L.png)

Comment: Please share the contents of your "Game Choice" box. Your issue is certainly there.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow !

You might want to give more details on what doesn't work exactly: does Pepper start listening ? (recognizable by the blue turning eyes ?) Does she seem to understand what you say (you can see it in the "Dialoge" log window - you can also try directly entering your commands in there). Do you get any errors in the logs?

I'm not sure how your Speech Recognition and Game Choice work together; if you're using the Speech Recognition then you should loop back to it after the Say, and if the Choice works without the speech recognition (I'm not sure which boxes exactly you're using, from memory I think there's a Choice box that includes the listening, and another box whose name I forget that works more like a switch case), then you may want to remove the Speech Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example which I hope helps.

[image]

Points of note:

- Here I've used Speech Recognition and Switch Case boxes (and you'd normally have a Say box at the front asking a question). You can replace the Say + Speech Recognition with a Choice box, but you'll still need the Switch Case box to split the signals based on the value. It looks like you've created a custom box doing this already though.
- The Start Behavior box needs a String input (which behavior to start). Note that this is the folder name of the behavior (not including behavior.xar). The easiest way to give this input is with a Text Edit, but you could also just edit the script in the Start Behavior box.